# StringBuilder Is not working When its under ForEach loop

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Here I am Having Some names But name is not binding  to String Builder

```
var x=from n in d.Employee
 Where n.EmpId==10
select n

 foreach (var master in x)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder abc = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(master.CANDIDATE_NAME + ",";
                abc.Append(sb);
                join_Body = new HrEmailsender()
                {
     Body = "Hi," + abc +                   
                };
```

Please Give me Appropriator hint for solving this issue

Comment: Declare your `StringBuilder` outside of the `foreach` loop

Comment: That line `sb.Append(master.CANDIDATE_NAME + ",";` won't compile since it misses a closing `)`

Comment: Also please check if `abc.Append(sb);` is really what you want. Seems redundant too.

Comment: @nilsK - will it even compile? Can you append a `StringBuilder` instance?

Comment: I guess, did not tested it. But there is an overload of `Append`, that accepts `Object`.

Comment: @RandRandom It will compile. see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.append?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_StringBuilder_Append_System_Object_)

Comment: @Izzy - never used it for anything else than to Input strings, thought you had to manually call `.ToString()` and not that it would accept an object. TIL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating a new stringbuilder (sb, abc) in each loop but you want only one stringbuilder which something is added to in each loop, create the stringbuilders outside of the loop:

```
var x=from n in d.Employee
     Where n.EmpId==10
    select n

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    StringBuilder abc = new StringBuilder();

     foreach (var master in x)
                {

                    sb.Append(master.CANDIDATE_NAME + ",");
                    abc.Append(sb);
                    join_Body = new HrEmailsender()
                    {
         Body = "Hi," + abc +                   
                    };
```

Comment: @DUKLEOSTEUS tHANK U SOO MUCH FOR YOUR EFFORT

Answer (score 0):

You will have to declare string builder outside for each loop. 
also the message body should be generated after foreach loop so that all names are included.

```
var x=from n in d.Employee
      Where n.EmpId==10
      select n

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder abc = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var master in x)
{
    sb.Append(master.CANDIDATE_NAME + ",");
    abc.Append(sb);

}
join_Body = new HrEmailsender()
{
    Body = "Hi," + abc.ToString();                  
};
```

Comment: Choudhari    Thank you soo much for your value fEED bACK iTS wORKING gOOD